# Make full part of grid page a different background color

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want background color from block 3 to block 6  to be different, but without any padding and margin. Like its full page background color.How can i do it?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 1.5%;
  row-gap: 1.5%;
  margin-bottom: 30%;
}
div {padding:5%; border:1px gray solid;}
```

```html
<div class  = "container">
<div>
1
</div>
<div>
2
</div>
<div>
3
</div><div>
4
</div><div>
5
</div>
<div>
6
</div>
<div>
7
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to change the background color of `.container` but only where blocks 3 through 6 are? Or do you want the background color to be applied to blocks 1 through 6? It's not clear to me.

Comment: @RobMoll  3 though 6, But i dont want to use another container for 3-6 blocks. Is it possuble?

Comment: Sorry. I have a typo in my first comment.I meant to say "3 through 6" in both cases. Ultimately the question is, should the background be on `.container` or on the 4 divs (3 through 6)? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @RobMoll on the 4 divs. But its 4 div, not one big like the answer below. Div 1-2 and 7  are unchanged

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px gray solid;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  background: red;
}
.item2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  background: green;
}
.item3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 4 / 3;
  background: blue;
}
.item4 {
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 2;
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="item item3">
    3-6
  </div>
  <div class="item item4">
    7
  </div>
</div>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/qBaMoVm

Comment: Its not  what i actually mean. I want there to be 4 blocks, not 1 big, But i  dont know if its possible.  I know that i can create blocks inside 3-6 block, but i need another option.

Comment: You want 4 blocks in the 3-6 block

Answer (score 0):

I would bet there is a more elegant way to do this, but I think I have what you are looking for here by overriding the `row-gap` with negative margins. I did not do anything to close the `column-gap` on blocks 3 to 6, but should be able to accomplish the same effect with negative margins.

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 1.5%;
  row-gap: 1.5%;
  margin-bottom: 30%;
}
div {padding:5%; border:1px gray solid;}

div.specialDiv {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

div.specialDiv.bott {
  margin-top: -.375%;       
  margin-bottom: -.75%;
}

div.specialDiv.top {
   margin-top: -.75%;
   margin-bottom: -.375%;
}
```

```html
<div class  = "container">
<div>
1
</div>
<div>
2
</div>
<div class="specialDiv top">
3
</div>
<div class="specialDiv top">
4
</div>
<div class="specialDiv bott">
5
</div>
<div class="specialDiv bott">
6
</div>
<div>
7
</div>
</div>
```